# Echo JSON encoded data

Tags: json, codeigniter, api, encoding

Im using Codeigniter RESTful API to get the data from from database based on the input. Now I want to change the way of displaying my json output in different way.

**CODE:**

```
function categoryskills_get()
{
    $category = $this->get('category');
    $skills = $this->Users_model->categoryskills($category);
    if($skills != FALSE)
    {
        $sub_cat = 0;
        foreach($skills['skills'] as $row)
        {
            $data[$skills['cat']][]['sub_category'] = $row['sub_cat'];
            $data[$skills['cat']][]['skills'] = $row['s_name'];
        }
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["status"] = '404';
        $response["error_msg"] = "Category not found!";
        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Above code is the controller for my http request.

**Current output**:

```
{
"Consultants": [
    {
        "sub_category": "Consultants"
    },
    {
        "skills": "Career Counsellor, Creative Consultant,Digital Consultant"
    },
    {
        "sub_category": "Accounting"
    },
    {
        "skills": "Accountant,Auditor,Tax Specialist"
    }

 ]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
"Consultants": [
    {
        "sub_category": "Consultants",
        "skills": "Career Counsellor,Creative Consultant,Digital Consultant"
    },
    {
     .....
    }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function categoryskills_get()
{
    $category = $this->get('category');
    $skills = $this->Users_model->categoryskills($category);
    if($skills != FALSE)
    {
        $sub_cat = 0;
        foreach($skills['skills'] as $key=>$row)
        {
            $data[$skills['cat']][$key]['sub_category'] = $row['sub_cat'];
            $data[$skills['cat']][$key]['skills'] = $row['s_name'];
        }
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["status"] = '404';
        $response["error_msg"] = "Category not found!";
        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Use foreach as key,value and placed $key into array like this  `$data[$skills['cat']][$key]['sub_category']` 
you will get desired output

Answer (score 2):

just make seperate temp array for sub_cat, and skills

```
$category = $this->get('category');
    $skills = $this->Users_model->categoryskills($category);
    $data = array();//create an empty array
    if($skills != FALSE)
    {
        $sub_cat = 0;
        foreach($skills['skills'] as $row)
        {
            $arr['sub_category'] = $row['sub_cat'];
            $arr['skills'] = $row['s_name'];//makes an $arr array

            $data[$skills['cat']][] = $arr;  //and after that add it to                        main array
        }
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["status"] = '404';
        $response["error_msg"] = "Category not found!";
        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function categoryskills_get()
{
    $category = $this->get('category');
    $skills = $this->Users_model->categoryskills($category);
    if($skills != FALSE)
    {
        $sub_cat = 0;
        foreach($skills['skills'] as $row)
        {
            $data[$skills['cat']][] = array('sub_category'=>$row['sub_cat'],'skills'=>$row['s_name']);
        }
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["status"] = '404';
        $response["error_msg"] = "Category not found!";
        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_push()` method like below:

```
$category = $this->get('category');
    $skills = $this->Users_model->categoryskills($category);
    $data = array();//create an empty array
    if($skills != FALSE)
    {
        $sub_cat = 0;
        foreach($skills['skills'] as $row)
        {
            $arr['sub_category'] = $row['sub_cat'];
            $arr['skills'] = $row['s_name'];//makes an $arr array
            array_push($data[$skills['cat']], $arr);//push array
        }
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["status"] = '404';
        $response["error_msg"] = "Category not found!";
        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```